# Does this code lend itself to a generalized routine?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Here is code I just wrote in the context of Linq2Sql:

```
 public static CampaignEntity GetOrCreate(int pid, SynchDBDataContext db)
    {
        CampaignEntity ce = (from c in db.CampaignEntities
                             where c.pid == pid
                             select c).FirstOrDefault();
        if (ce == null)
        {
            ce = new CampaignEntity();
            ce.pid = pid;
            db.CampaignEntities.InsertOnSubmit(ce);
        }

        return ce;
    }
```

The things to make a generic routine would be: 
- the entity type
- the type of the primary key column
- the value of the primary key

Comment: You could only do this if the `pid` property/field were part of an interface or base entity type that you could constrain a generic parameter on.

Comment: if you make that command an answer, i'll mark it as such

Answer (score 2):

What I've seen done before is something like this:

```
public static TEntity GetOrCreate<TEntity, TPKey>(TPKey pid, SyncDBCataContext db,  Func<int, TEntity> create){...}
```

The Func would be the method that creates the entity, so you could inline it when you call this function or you could take this out and hard-code how an entity is created like you have done in your question.

Here is a method that will get by id:

```
public T GetById<TEntity, TPKey>(TPKey id, DataContext context) where TEntity : class
{
        MetaTable metaTable = context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(TEntity));
        MetaDataMember primaryKeyMetaDataMember = metaTable.RowType.DataMembers.SingleOrDefault(d => d.IsPrimaryKey);
        return context.GetTable<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(GetEqualityLambdaExpression<TEntity>(primaryKeyMetaDataMember.Name, id));
}
```

Here is a method that will create the expression for the filter needed by the get by id method:

```
public Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetEqualityLambdaExpression<T>(string fieldName, object constantValue)
{
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, fieldName),
        Expression.Constant(constantValue)),
        new ParameterExpression[] { param });
    return expression;
}
```

As you can see there is some use of reflection.  If performance is a big concern, you can implement some sort of caching to reduce the overhead in future calls.

Comment: You should only use `` for inline code. If it is a block of code, you put four spaces before each line, and all other spacing will be preserved.

Comment: That explains a lot, I wondered why my code looked off. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that in my edit I fixed the last two blocks, but completely wrecked the first. Sorry for that, I guess I was a bit distracted.

Comment: at the time you posted this answer i didn't have enough understanding of c# expressions - i still don't but its not greek to me now - do you feel this should be marked the answer? for *my* level of understanding, the answer is really that I can't do it bec. c# templates just don't let you